# Confused of "beat around the bush"

Tags: meaning, idioms

I have searched "beat around the bush" but it seems that it has two meanings based on my understanding.

First is it's like you're insinuating or implying a topic/question to someone so it is not directly stated but that's really what you want to be answered by the one you are talking to.

Second is digressing from the topic to avoid for some reason, like you're in a conversation with your friend, and he keeps telling a story about your ex-girlfriend without knowing you and your girlfriend already broke up, then you digress from it by inserting the school-related topics.

I'm confused whether I just misundertand it or it really has two meanings, if it has, which one of these is mostly used?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, allow me to change it.

Comment: Your two definitions above refer to the same activity, even if the motivation is different.

Comment: BTW, I have corrected some errors in grammar without affecting the intent of my post. Does that mean I didn't misunderstand the meaning?

Comment: I just thought that I misused "digress" in this post, I'm willingly accept any correction to my post like grammar errors, misuse of words etc.

Comment: I think that "avoiding directly saying something by instead saying something that is sort of related to the thing in question but really only hints at it" is the primary sense of "beating around the bush." The digressive meaning that you mention might fall more comfortably under the heading of "changing the subject."

Comment: As with the other comments, I only see a single meaning in the examples in the question.

Comment: @JasonBassford I disagree. A speaker beats about the bush when they fail to come to the point, from embarrassment or whatever. A second speaker bringing up another topic so as to _stop_ them from coming to the point is, as Sven says, changing the subject.